# How to create separate relations tables, using Sequelize?

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I see that Sequelize allows us to setup various relationships between models, but it just creates another column, referencing the ID of the associated model. For instance:

```
const Comment = require('../Comment/CommentModel')

  const User =  db.define('User', {
    email: { type: DataTypes.STRING, unique: true},    
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    isActive:{type:DataTypes.BOOLEAN,defaultValue:true},
    photo: DataTypes.STRING
  });

  User.hasMany(Comment, {as: 'Comments'})
```

This will add a UserId column in the "comments" table.

Problem is, i'm used to working with actual relationship tables, and using JOIN to fetch the needed data. For example, I would make another table called users_comments, which would have both userId and  commentId columns.

1) Is there some way to setup it up automatically with Sequelize?

2) Isn't referencing the associated "entity" in a given table considered bad practice? I mean, what are JOINs for? Why should "comment" be aware that a "user" might possess it? And what if one day i decide that a comment might belong to multiple users(of course this is an unrealistic example, but you get the point).

Thank you for any input on the subject.